# Predicate logic - which formal rules of logic need to be used to prove this quantifiers logic expression?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The question being taken from a logical point of view, I simplify the question (without providing context) but I can provide context if users ask to.

Let be three sets $A, B$ and $C$.

The question is how to simplify this logical statement:

> ($\forall a\in A, \exists b \in B$) and ($\forall b\in B, \exists c\in C$)

into:

> $\forall a\in A, \exists c\in C$

---

To be more specific, we have:
$r=lcm(\delta_1, ..., \delta_m)$ where the $\delta_i$ are all the possible orders of elements in the group $U_p$ ($p$ is an odd prime).

We write $r=q_1^{\alpha_1}... q_k^{\alpha_k}$

By number theory considerations we have that $\forall j\in [\![1,k]\!], \exists i\in [\![1,m]\!], \delta_i = a q_j ^{\alpha_j}$ (where $a\in\mathbb N).$

On the other hand, we have: $\forall i\in [\![1,m]\!], \exists x \in U_p$ such that $\delta_i$ is the order of $x$.

My question in this context is: how to prove that $\forall j \in [\![1,k]\!], \exists x\in U_p$ ?

---

I perfectly understand why we can simplify the first expression into the second one, but what I am asking here is: which formal rules of logic should we apply to the first expression in order to arrive to the second one.

Many thanks in advance.

Edit:

I realize it's not about "simplifying" but about inferring expression $2$ from expression $1$.

Comment: Universal Instantiation and Existential Elimination on the first formula, call it P, to get P(a,b). Then UI and EE again on the second one to get Q(b,c) on the second one. Then conclude by Exist Intro and Univ Intro.

Comment: What is/are the predicates involved in your question? Is the same predicate for all statements?

Comment: you need elimination and generalization rules for both quantifiers. to be any more specific we would need to know which inference rules are you working with? the basic underlying reasoning is hypothetical syllogism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note we respresent the statement $\forall a \in A, \exists b \in B$ in first-order logic (FOL) as $\forall x \exists y [x \in A \to y \in B]$ where $x,y$ are variables denoting arbitrary elements. In other words, we say "for every element $x$, there exists at least one element $y$ such that, if $x \in A$, then $y \in B$." Similarly, we respresent the statements $\forall b \in B, \exists c \in C$ and $\forall a \in A, \exists c \in C$ as $\forall y \exists z [y \in B \to z \in C]$ and $\forall x \exists z [x \in A \to z \in C]$, respectively. With this in mind, below I offer a proof of the argument

$$ \forall x \exists y [x \in A \to y \in B], \forall y \exists z [y \in B \to z \in C] \vdash \forall x \exists z [x \in A \to z \in C] $$

in a FOL natural deduction system using the following inference rules:

$
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{$\forall$E} &\text{Universal Elimination} \\
\text{$\forall$I} &\text{Universal Introduction} \\
\text{$\exists$E} &\text{Existential Elimination} \\
\text{$\exists$I} &\text{Existential Introduction} \\
\text{MP} &\text{Modus Ponens} \\
\text{CP} &\text{Conditional Proof (Arrow Introduction)} \\
\text{Assumption for CP} &\text{Assumption for Conditional Proof} \\
\text{Assumption for TD} &\text{Assumption for Typical Disjunct} \\
\end{array}
$

The proof is as follows:

$
\begin{array}{llll}
\{1\} & 1. & \forall x \exists y [x \in A \to y \in B] & \text{premise} \\
\{2\} & 2. & \forall y \exists z [y \in B \to z \in C] & \text{premise} \\
\{1\} & 3. & \exists y [a \in A \to y \in B] & \text{1 $\forall$E} \\
\{4\} & 4. & a \in A \to b \in B & \text{Assumption of TD} \\
\{2\} & 5. & \exists z [b \in B \to z \in C] & \text{2 $\forall$E} \\
\{6\} & 6. & b \in B \to c \in C & \text{Assumption of TD} \\
\{7\} & 7. & a \in A & \text{Assumption for CP} \\
\{4,7\} & 8. & b \in B & \text{4,7 MP} \\
\{4,6,7\} & 9. & c \in C & \text{6,8 MP} \\
\{4,6\} & 10. & a \in A \to c \in C & \text{7,9 CP} \\
\{4,6\} & 11. & \exists z [a \in A \to z \in C] & \text{10 $\exists$I} \\
\{2,4\} & 12. & \exists z [a \in A \to z \in C] & \text{5,6,11 $\exists$E} \\
\{1,2\} & 13. & \exists z [a \in A \to z \in C] & \text{3,4,12 $\exists$E} \\
\{1,2\} & 14. & \forall x \exists z [x \in A \to z \in C] & \text{13 $\forall$I} & \square \\
\end{array}
$

In short, we know from lines $1,2$ that for every $x \in A$ there is at least one $y \in B$ and for every $y \in B$ there is at least one $z \in C$, respectively. Let $a$ be any element in $A$ (line $3$). Then, according to line $1$ there must exist an element in $B$, which we will call $b$. In turn, according to line $2$ there must exist and element in $C$, which we will call $c$. Hence, if $a$ is an element $A$, then there must be some element $c \in C$ (line $10$). Now, notice the choice of $a,b,c$ was completely arbitrary, and I did not attribute any properties to these elements besides membership to their respective sets. For this reason, I can generalize my conclusions and state that for every $x \in A$ there is at least one $z \in C$ (line $14$).